# Jenkins permission denied when i am copying my index.html file to /var/www/html

Tags: security, jenkins, permissions, permission-denied, sudoers

How can we solve the Jenkins permission denied issue? I do know that this can be solved by adding Jenkins user in the sudoers file, but that's not a recommended method as it can cause a security problem

How can we give Jenkins only the permissions it needs to perform its tasks and nothing more?

I was told a good approach would be to add jenkins to a group and then give permissions

Comment: The copying action run on host, or  from host to container, or something else?